Is this an expected functionality in LWS? (LWS and window.top)
Are these results expected when executing the code block below in the LWS Console?
const a = 't',b='o',c='p'; const full = `${a}${b}${c}`;

const t = 'top' in window && window.top;
const t0 = 'top' in window && window.top;
const t1 = 'top' in window && window['top'];// using ''.
const t2 = 'top' in window && window["top"];// using "".
const t3 = 'top' in window && window[`top`];// using ``.
const t4 = 'top' in window && window[full];
const t5 = 'top' in window && window[`${a}${b}${c}`];

console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t===t0); // true
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t===t1); // false
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t===t2); // 
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t===t3);// false
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t===t4);// false
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t===t5);// false

console.log('================================')
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t1===t0); // false
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t1===t1); // true
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t1===t2); // true
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t1===t3); // true
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t1===t4); // true
console.log('ioConnect: top is the same in both ways:', t1===t5); // true

Some BG: I was looking for a possible way to migrate some VF code into LWC combined with lwc:dom="manual" in the html definition file. So, I saw that when I try to access window.top in code it was replaced by window === globalThis ? top : window.top. On the other hand, when I try to use  window['top'] it stays the way it is.
Here are the results when compiled (not when using the LWS console):

^ returns the globalThis/window.top

^ expectedly returns Proxified 'window'
If this is not an expected behavior where / how to report it?

Adding some console log statements shows what's happening:
console.log("t", t);
console.log("t0", t0);
console.log("t1", t1);
console.log("t2", t2);
console.log("t3", t3);
console.log("t4", t4);
console.log("t5", t5);

LWS Output:
t Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
t0 Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
t1 null
t2 null
t3 null
t4 null
t5 null

LS Output (SecureWindow):
t {document: {…}, navigator: {…}, MutationObserver: ƒ, XMLHttpRequest: ƒ, …}
t0 {document: {…}, navigator: {…}, MutationObserver: ƒ, XMLHttpRequest: ƒ, …}
t1 {document: {…}, navigator: {…}, MutationObserver: ƒ, XMLHttpRequest: ƒ, …}
t2 {document: {…}, navigator: {…}, MutationObserver: ƒ, XMLHttpRequest: ƒ, …}
t3 {document: {…}, navigator: {…}, MutationObserver: ƒ, XMLHttpRequest: ƒ, …}
t4 {document: {…}, navigator: {…}, MutationObserver: ƒ, XMLHttpRequest: ƒ, …}
t5 {document: {…}, navigator: {…}, MutationObserver: ƒ, XMLHttpRequest: ƒ, …}

Enabling debug mode tells a more interesting story:
t Window {0: Window, window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
t0 Window {0: Window, window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
t1 Proxy(Object) {}
t2 Proxy(Object) {}
t3 Proxy(Object) {}
t4 Proxy(Object) {}
t5 Proxy(Object) {}

In other words, string keys are wrapped in a security proxy, but window.top is not.
I would consider this a bug. It can be reported to Salesforce Technical Support. If you do so, please let me know what the case number is for reference. I'll bring attention to it.

could you please check the images I uploaded. They are from built LWC components, not just checks in the LWS Console. Thanks again

In Lightning Web Security, only window.top (ie. direct property access) will work. It is currently published in Limitations for Aura Components With LWS
, so I think we'll need to revise those docs to indicate that it applies to Aura and LWC.
